# autoplay html audio created with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I did this little script that can control the playing of an audio track on a webpage.

```js
var source = "audio/burger.mp3"
var audio = document.createElement("audio");
audio.load()
audio.addEventListener("load", function() {
  audio.play();
}, true);
audio.src = source;



$("#playBtn").click(function() {
  audio.play();
});

$("#pauseBtn").click(function() {
  audio.pause();
});

$("#stopBtn").click(function() {
  audio.pause();
  audio.currentTime = 0;
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id="playBtn"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><i class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true" id="pauseBtn"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><i class="fa fa-stop" aria-hidden="true" id="stopBtn"></i></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I would like know if there is a way for play the file on the page load.
I know this way, It's something really 90s but I have to test something on the page.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you should use "autoplay" attribute with your audio tag.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp

Answer (score 6):

Add *.autoplay = true; before you load.

```
 var source = "audio/burger.mp3"
 var audio = document.createElement("audio");
 //
 audio.autoplay = true;
 //
 audio.load()
 audio.addEventListener("load", function() { 
     audio.play(); 
 }, true);
 audio.src = source;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `autoplay` attribute on your audio element. Also, try to prefer using the `Audio()` constructor when generating an Audio element in JavaScript. Lastly, don't call `audio.load()` here, setting the `src` value in this case triggers that automatically.

```js
var source = "https://html5music.herokuapp.com/media/no_words.webm";
var audio = new Audio(); // use the constructor in JavaScript, just easier that way
audio.addEventListener("load", function() {
  audio.play();
}, true);
audio.src = source;
audio.autoplay = true; // add this

$("#playBtn").click(function() {
  audio.play();
});

$("#pauseBtn").click(function() {
  audio.pause();
});

$("#stopBtn").click(function() {
  audio.pause();
  audio.currentTime = 0;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id="playBtn"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><i class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true" id="pauseBtn"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><i class="fa fa-stop" aria-hidden="true" id="stopBtn"></i></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: copy-pasted this solution into my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gallex/1re11kxo/) - music starts to play, but play/pause/stop buttons not working. what i'm missing?

Comment: @Gallex you're missing jQuery

Comment: unable to play with this stream link `http://31.14.40.149:8000/;stream.mp3`

Comment: With new browser autoplay policies, solutions like these don't work anymore :(.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [autoplay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) attribute on the audio tag.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Patrick Roberts' suggestion on using `new Audio` instead of `document.createElement('audio`)`. However, for audio to autoplay on page load, you don't need to add any event listeners. Setting:

1. a valid media source
2. `audio.autoplay = true`

will make the audio start playing as soon as it is loaded. So the JS part could be simplified as:

```
var source = "audio/burger.mp3"
var audio = new Audio();
// no event listener needed here
audio.src = source;
audio.autoplay = true;

$("#playBtn").click(function() {
  audio.play();
});

$("#pauseBtn").click(function() {
  audio.pause();
});

$("#stopBtn").click(function() {
  audio.pause();
  audio.currentTime = 0;
});
```

However, this thread is a bit dated, and policy has changed since. Staring in 2017, safari 11+ on iOS and MacOS as well as chrome 64+ no longer support audio/video autoplay. See:  [autoplay policy changes for macOS](https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/) and [autoplay policy changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).

Safari implemented a blocker on media that autoplay with sound, so autoplay is disabled by default. Users have to manually enable this feature. They recommend developers add a snippet to detect this behavior:

```
var promise = document.querySelector('video').play();

if (promise !== undefined) {
    promise.catch(error => {
        // Auto-play was prevented
        // Show a UI element to let the user manually start playback
    }).then(() => {
        // Auto-play started
    });
}
```